# Django 2.0.3 Не отображаются картинки

Tags: django, изображения

**Здравствуйте. Не отображаются картинки в Django ver 2.0.3**

Для загрузки картинок установлена библиотека Pillow.

Ссылки корректные, но по ним изображение не находит.

Сервер из коробки с django.

Кроме этих строчек в settings.py ничего не добавлял

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Методы из интернета не помогают, либо слишком старые.

Comment: «Ссылки корректные» — не верю.

Comment: какие методы не помогают?

Comment: Как запускаете Django-проект?

Comment: 1. Как запускаете Django-проект?
- Есть виртульное окружение. Запускаю его. А дальше в папке проекта ч/з консоль ...runserver

Comment: 2. какие методы не помогают?
- Пробовал дописать в настройках urls.py проекта 

`if settings.DEBUG: re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 
'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,}),`


- В настройках settings.py указал строки 

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` и `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`


- Подключив библиотеки 

`from django.conf.urls.static import static` и 
`from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns` 

дописывал в urls.py `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`

Comment: 3. «Ссылки корректные» — не верю.
- Корректные в том смысле, что когда на них переходишь - ошибка 404 - страница не найдена. 
 Однако если её переместить из папки, где она находится, система не показывает, что "файл не существует или был удалён".
 А чисто технически понимаю, что если картинки нет - значит ссылки не могут быть корректными.

Comment: [![ ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGJzy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGJzy.png)
А пробовал добавить это в url файл ?

Comment: Коля Карлов, сделал, как вы прислали. Заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Были такие же симптомы,
в главный urls.py добавил:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # какие-то наши пути
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Спасибо @Alex Shchegretsov !!